# install gedit with a specific libboost version

Tags: ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-16.04, gedit

I install boost 1.6.8 on ubuntu 16.04. Then the gnome editor (gedit) cannot start:

```
gedit: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I switch the previous version 1.58 to the current version 1.6.8 to make it work?